# flex setFocus on creation complete

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Normally, forms and pop Ups don't have the focus set when they are just displayed. The obvious solution was to set the focus to the first input in the creation complete event of the component, so the keyboard short Cuts like tab and space start working.

The problem is that, creation complete is not the panacea, sometimes the element is not focus-able at that point, and i am not sure why that happens.

The render event would ensure the focus, but it dispatches too much for a very simple purpose.

In which point a component is always ready to be focus-able?

Edit: The component giving me trouble to get start up focus, is a `TitleWindow`, which can be poped in 2 ways, a Mouse click event and a keyboard event.
When the tite window is displayed by a click, the first input gets focus in the creation complete event, but when displayed by a keyboard event, it doesnt...

By now i got it working with the following code:

```
private function titlewindow_creationCompleteHandler(e:FlexEvent):void{
    callLater( setTextInputFocus);
}
private function setTextInputFocus():void{
    txtPregunta.setFocus();
}
```

But doubt the way is shown has anything to do with this... because, some other `TitleWindow` are displayed this way too and they're fine.

So what could it be?

Comment: Which component?  Why wouldn't an element not be focus-able on creationComplete?

Comment: i have no idea... its just a PopUpManager.createPopUp(), the only thing that makes this one diferent from the others, is that this one shows with a keyboard event, insead of a component click.

Comment: These were your words: "The obvious solution was to set the focus to the first input in the creation complete event of the component".  I meant to ask component you were talking about.  The question edit answers that.  The input should be focusable in a creationComplete event handler regardless of how the component was created. Perhaps you should show us how you create the component and/or what the component is.

Comment: Ok, i will try to reproduce the problem with a short snipped.

Answer (score 0):

> The render event would ensure the focus, but it dispatches too much for a very simple purpose.

If this is true then why not try this:

```
private function titlewindow_creationCompleteHandler(e:FlexEvent):void{
    var callback : Function = function(re : Event) : void {
        titlewindow.removeEventHandler(RenderEvent.orsomething, callback);
        setTextInputFocus();
    };

    titlewindow.addEventHandler(RenderEvent.orsomething, callback);
}
```

Might be kind of a hack since it should be focusable on creationComplete but it would probably work.